# matlab function handle inside gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I created a GUI layout using Matlabs GUID application, essentially my problem is simple, i have a text box where I want to enter data, and a push button which i want to display that value entered inside the text box, the text box is define as

```
 function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 % hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
 % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
 % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 myString = get(hObject, 'String')
 set(hObject,'Value',str2num(myString));
```

at this point, i entered some numerical value into the text box, lets say 44, now 44 is stored inside the "Value" element of hObject for this function.

Now I want to output this value when a button is pushed

```
 function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
 % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
 % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 fHandle = @edit1_Callback
 get(fHandle,'Value')
```

^^^on this last line i should see some output(since i dont have a ";" which allows matlab to print out the data), the issue is....i get an error that says "Conversion to double from function_handle is not possible." , shouldnt I be able to call "get" using a function handle which points to my earlier function, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for

```
get(handles.edit1,'value')
```

All your uicontrols are stored in the handles. Knowing the tag of your uicontrol (for your edit box I guess this is `edit1`), you can get the handles of this object with `handles.edit1`.

You can even write

```
my_value = get(handles.edit1,'Value');
```